# Tutorial for spring boot with docker not working?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I've followed the official spring boot docker for gradle tutorial, but I can't make it work.

My `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
        classpath('gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:0.22.1')
    }
}

group = 'springio'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'

task unpack(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn bootJar
    from(zipTree(tasks.bootJar.outputs.files.singleFile))
    into("build/dependency")
}
docker {
    name "${project.group}/${bootJar.baseName}"
    copySpec.from(tasks.unpack.outputs).into("dependency")
    buildArgs(['DEPENDENCY': "dependency"])
}

bootJar {
    baseName = 'globalstatus'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

`gradlew build` gives me a valid and runnable JAR

But if I do `gradlew build docker` and then start the container I get

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Jib  https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib

Comment: Why is it /app.jar shouldn't it be app.jar in Entrypoint??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app.jar` should be an executable `jar` file but it is instead a directory. Because the `JAR_FILE` is not set as build argument the `COPY` instruction copies the content of the `<project_dir>/build/docker` directory to the `/app.jar` directory in the container. You can list it with:

```
 docker run --entrypoint="ls" springio/globalstatus -la /app.jar
```

To fix the build you need to change the docker task:

```
docker {
    name "${project.group}/${bootJar.baseName}"
    files bootJar.outputs
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': bootJar.archiveFileName.get()])
}
```

**Explanation:**
The [docker gradle plugin](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker) work directory is `<project_dir>/build/docker` so when the docker image is build file operations are relative to this path.

`files` copies the output of the `bootJar` task into the `build/docker` directory. The `buildArgs` sets the build argument `JAR_FILE` to the name of the archive (the spring boot jar file). When the image is build from `Dockerfile`, the `COPY` instruction will add the jar file to the root directory of the container.

Comment: This is the correct answer; however @earandap suggestion made me switch to a better solution.